# ON operator SQL, what is it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to understand some code and see that the "ON" operator was used in this query (using sql server).

```
SELECT A.*, B.UID
FROM Table1 A Left Outer Join
(SELECT ID FROM Table2) AS B ON A.ID= B.ID
...
```

What exactly does this operator do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ON` represents one or more `JOIN` conditions by which we could match records from one table to other.

For understanding how joins works visually, read following -

- [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)
- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's not an operator - it's a *part* of a `JOIN`, which is part of the [`FROM` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

It's very similar to a `WHERE` clause - except it is intended just to filter the joining of two tables (or rowsets).

In this case, it's the condition whereby rows from `A` and `B` are matched up. If you had the same conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it would affect the join - a `LEFT JOIN` (here) is allowed to find no matching row in `B` yet still contribute that row from `A` to the result (with `B`s columns being `NULL`). If you place the same condition in `WHERE`, it forces the join to become an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You just must be confused by the use of an inline query *(SELECT ID FROM Table2)* in the JOIN statement.  The query could have been written as:

```
SELECT A.*, B.UID
FROM Table1 A Left Outer Join Table2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

It denotes the association between fields in order to enforce a `JOIN`.